# Should I worry about gcc -pedantic option now?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, compiler-options

I have just started to learn C as a hobby. I am doing it with the "C programming: A Modern Approach" book. There is a first program there which is called `pun.c`. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int int_figure;
  float float_figure;

  int_figure = 12;
  float_figure = 12.0;
  printf("To C or not to C, this is a question\n");
  printf("%d\n", int_figure);
  printf("%.2f\n", float_figure);
  return 0;
}
```

Actually it does not matter because the thing I want to ask about is the same with any `.c` file compilation with `gcc`.

So in the book there are some options for `gcc` which allow finding errors during compilation.One of them is `-Wall`, another one is `-pedantic`. So when I compile the file with this option, the output in terminal is the following:

```
nickdudaev|c $ gcc -o -Wall pun pun.c
pun: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.0/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
pun: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.0/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
pun: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.0/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
pun:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.0/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
pun: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.0/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
pun: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.0/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/cc2TRR93.o: In function `main':
pun.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
pun:(.text+0xf6): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.0/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
pun:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in pun(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The program although runs correctly.

```
nickdudaev|c $ ./pun
To C or not to C, this is a question
12
12.00
```

So to the questions.

1. Should I on this stage (of learning) worry about this output and at all use those options?
2. Do I have probably some systematic error? Because output is the same for any file compilation. Maybe something is not properly installed?

I tried to search Google, but the only thing I found is descriptions of what `gcc` options do. But nothing about possible output and what to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
gcc -o -Wall pun pun.c
```

doesn't look right. You're saying `-Wall` where you should say the name of the output, i.e. the argument to `-o`.

Try:

```
gcc -Wall -o pun pun.c
```

Basically you're feeding `pun`, the old binary, to gcc as a source file.

Comment: Yes, it works without any errors this way. Thank you. I haven't thought about  wrong options order.

Answer (score 1):

The `-o` option in `gcc` is used to specify a custom output file name, otherwise,

> If `-o` is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in `a.out`.

The recommended format is `-o file`. The next expected argument after `-o` is a filename, not another switch. See the [online manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) for more details.

You should re-write your compilation statement as

```
gcc -o pun pun.c -Wall
```

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now that I mixed it in a wrong way. Both versions work fine.